# Android SDK fast reading of primitives from file

Tags: android, performance, nio

In my application I need to read 80K ints from a file as fast as possible. So I tried to accomplish it by nio, using FileChannel and ByteBuffer (and IntBuffer in this case) to write and to read array of ints.

Here is example of code

```
public static int[] loadByMappedBuffer(Context context, String filename) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
    FileChannel ch = fis.getChannel();

    MappedByteBuffer mbuff = ch.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, ch.size());
    IntBuffer ibuff = mbuff.asIntBuffer();

    int[] array = new int[ibuff.limit()];
    ibuff.get(array);

    fis.close();
    ch.close();

    return array;
}
```

on my machine it work's perfect with result of 6-7 ms, but in Android executing this method takes over then 900 ms. The same thing happend when I'm reading other primitives from file, using this approach.

I don't think that there are needs to describe characteristics of my emulated device, but here they are:

- 1907 RAM
- ARM CPU
- 64 VM Heap
- data Partition - 100 M

one more thing: when I'm reading array of bytes, which has the same length, using FileInputStream it takes only 2-3 ms, when in my mashite it takes 0.5 ms. So you can see the difference.

Any ideas will be appreciated) Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Recently I had perfomed some tests, so here are results

- Sony Ericsson Experia with best time of 104 ms and worst of 270 ms
- Nexus 7 with best time of 20.14 ms and wors of 48.36
- Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 (2014 Edition) with best time of 1.16 ms and worst of 5.82 (XD this is my kid)

Comment: You are testing on an emulated device? And you are complaining that the emulated device is slow? That shouldn't surprise you. Try to run it on a real device first.

Comment: @XaverKapeller but there is such a big difference, I mean 7 vs 900 ms

Comment: and I making my application for a handsets

Comment: Well yes, that should illustrate to you how slow the android emulator is. Just test on a real device, I never ever use emulators. They are basically useless unless you need to test something which can only really be tested on an emulator.

Comment: ok, I will test in on my handset and tablet and answer you, thanks for advice)

Comment: @XaverKapeller I added results of testing

Comment: @XaverKapeller Hi again, I think that I need your advice, so if you have time and wish take a look at this question pleace (it related with this) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664382/android-ways-to-speed-up-few-readings-from-files