# Android ways to speed up few readings from files

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, nio

In my application I need to load some files, when the app starts. I have 6 different files, which content int arrays and I need to read them as fast as possible. 3 of them content 80K ints, other 200K ints

Here is method that I'm using to read int array from file

```
public static int[] loadByMappedBuffer(Context context, String filename) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
    FileChannel ch = fis.getChannel();

    MappedByteBuffer mbuff = ch.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, ch.size());
    IntBuffer ibuff = mbuff.asIntBuffer();

    int[] array = new int[ibuff.limit()];
    ibuff.get(array);

    fis.close();
    ch.close();

    return array;
}
```

As you see I'm using nio to read arrays.
Here is result of testing, when I'm reding single file, which content 80K ints

- Sony Ericsson Experia with best time of 104 ms and worst of 270 ms
- Nexus 7 with best time of 20.14 ms and wors of 48.36
- Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 (2014 Edition) with best time of 1.16 ms and worst of 5.82

So for single reading it works fine, but when I'm reading all 6 files (which I mentioned above) the results will be following

- Sony Ericsson Experia with best time of 1396 ms and worst of 3324 ms
- Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 (2014 Edition) with best time of 58 ms and worst of 115 ms

First of all I don't understand why cache don't kicks in after first reading, like on PC.

At this time I have 2 ideas

1. find a better way to read files (but nio is the fastest way to read primitives from files, as far as I know)
2. use MT programming and put file readings to threads, which will speed up this, but only for devices, which has CPU with more than one core, I'm right?

I had heared that Async Task is something like threads, can it bee helpful for my purpose?

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Not that much delay  and not that much to do to improve. Better let it be but notice the user of the delay with a progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

threads are not only for parallel computing, they're used for better UX, so the user can still interact with the app while it's doing stuff in the background. 
AsyncTask is very nice, although if you're short on time a simple thread written correctly should be faster.

now, if the app loads files, you can do it in parts (like 10% of every file), show those parts, and continue to load the rest in the background.

i think trying to read faster is the wrong direction here, because that's very hardware dependent. some devices would be slow no matter how hard you try.. think about a UX that's OK for all cases.

hope that helps

Comment: thanks for your advice, so youre said that the best way to accomplis it will be loading files in the background, I'm properly understand? but It will have the same speed and I need data, stored un files in next activity

Comment: yes you understand properly:) now i'm not sure i understood the question. if you want to share those ints between activities you can use static variables - not very elegent but it'll do the trick.

Comment: no, I mean I need data, stored in files after starting main activity (rather displaying it, which happens after ending of onCreate() method ) and opening another activity by clicking the button, which can take only a second. And as far as I see the process on the background can load files not on time

Comment: so if someone click on button, wait until you're finished loading, and display a progress hud meanwhile. that's acceptable?

Comment: nope, I think that better way would be display progress hud at the start of the app then the 2 (in worst case) seconds will not seem so long.

You know, now I'm thinking to put some file readings to thread(or even threads), which could load data in parallel to other loading, which starts in `onCreate()` I know that this speed up loading for devices with more then one cores, but this better then nothing)

Comment: so thanks for your answer and I shell message you, when I deal with it
P.S. have a nice day, dude